# How can I determine the spin of a molecule?

Tags: spin, statistical-mechanics

I was reading statistical mechanics today and came across a line

> For $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{N2},$ we get half-spin, and that is why we get $σ = 2$ in their rotational partition equation.

I didn't understand it quite well! What does this line mean, actually? And how can I determine the spin of $\ce{O2}$ or $\ce{N2}?$

Secondly, how did they state that $σ = 2?$

Reference:
Haque. Physical Chemistry 4, 8th ed.; Shams Publication, 2021; Vol. 1.

Comment: Generally, it may be good to quote a broader context and marking the confusing part. // Your own reasoning – based on searching, reading and thinking – is supposed to be present to avoid the question closure for lack of own explicit  effort.

Comment: Did you read the box only? Certainly the book introduce that before.

Comment: @Alchimista, what box?

Comment: Quoting more than one sentence would be helpful. But I'd guess that you're probably looking for something called *nuclear spin statistics*.